# Crear columna en dataframe de python con condiciones que considera a los valores de las demás columnas para asignarle un valor

Tags: python, pandas

Soy algo nueva en Python, y me gustaría conocer ideas sobre como hacer lo siguiente en un dataframe.

*Quiero crear la columna "Esquema" que tenga las siguientes condiciones, es decir considera sus demás columnas para asignar un valor ahí:*

**Caso 1.**

Si el registro (consideramos los registros iguales por fila) tiene más de una cobertura (es decir si la columna "cobertura" tiene números distintos por fila), y cada una tiene el mismo monto, se coloca en la columna esquema, la cve_esquema que pertenezca a la columna cob_basica= "V".

**Caso 2.**

Si registro tiene más de una cobertura y los montos son distintos, se coloca el esquema de reaseguro de la cob_basica= "V" a las filas que tengan el mismo monto, y el que tenia monto distinto se asigna su cve_esquema en la columna Esquema (como el ejemplo del registro 157)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se hace en resumen es asignar a la columna "Esquema" la cve de esquema según las anteriores condiciones
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Ariana, bienvenida, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener otra medalla!

Comment: El ejemplo del registro 157 no encaja con lo que dices que quieres hacer. Ese ejemplo efectivamente tiene más de una cobertura, pero los montos de sus tres primeras entradas son iguales (48518) por lo que deberían recibir 407 en el resultado. Aún si alguno fuese diferente, no sé de dónde saldría el 408 que has puesto en el resultado, pues ese valor (408) no aparece en ningún momento en la columna "Esquema".

Comment: Hola! cve_esquema no tiene ningún orden, ya que lo que busca asignarse es un cve_esquema a la columna esquema, en ese caso se ignora el 408, porque al ser los montos iguales en tres registros se toma el valor cve_esquema que tiene la cob_basica que fue 407, y se añadió 5788 a la otra columna porque el monto era distinto

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar numpy para hacer un CASE donde puedas evaluar estas condiciones, te comparto el siguiente ejemplo:

```
df[Nueva_Columna] = np.select([(CONDICIONES)], [VALORES_SI], VALOR_SI_NO)
```

Para ser un poco mas claro, imaginemos que tienes un Dataframe que contiene todos tus datos y tu quieres crear una condición en base a valores nulos, harías algo así:

```
    df['nueva_columna'] = np.select([(df['columna'].isnull())], ['Valor no Nulo'], df['columna'])
```

Recuerda que cuando crees las condiciones debes evaluarlas haciendo uso de (paréntesis) o te dará error